# Woocommerce API creating product with variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to create a product with variations, but the product got created and the two prices too, the problem is that when I go to the shop, there appears no options no choose between them. And documentation is not clear about this nor I find any help.

There is my code:

```
data = {
    "name": product.name,
    "type": "variable",
    "images": image,
    "sku": product.sku,
    'description': str(product.description),

    'attributes': [
        {
            'name': 'Payment',
            'options': ['Once', 'Monthly']
        },
    ]
}
woo_product = wcapi.post("products", data).json()
attribute_id = woo_product["attributes"][0]["id"]
product.woocommerce_id = woo_product["id"]
product.save()

# Variation
data_variation = {
    "regular_price": str(product.once_price),
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Payment",
            "option": "Once",
        }
    ]
}

wcapi.post(f"products/{woo_product['id']}/variations", data_variation).json()

data_variation = {
    "regular_price": str(product.price),
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Payment",
            "option": "Monthly",
        }
    ]
}
wcapi.post(f"products/{woo_product['id']}/variations", data_variation).json()
```

I want the variations to be choosable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the product creation to this worked:

```
data = {
        "name": product.name,
        "type": "variable",
        #"regular_price": str(product.price),
        "images": image,
        "sku": product.sku,
        'description': str(product.description),

        'attributes': [
            {
                'name': 'Payment',
                'variation': True,
                'visible': True,
                'options': ['Once', 'Monthly']
            },
        ]
    }
```